# why my php app code shows only one result from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have write these kind of codes multiple times and it always worked great but now that I am on a different system it shows only 1 result.

the query is simple

```
$HOST = 'localhost';
$USERNAME = 'root';
$PASSWORD = '';
$DATABASE = 'db_test';


$con = mysqli_connect($HOST,$USERNAME,$PASSWORD,$DATABASE);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test ";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$res_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

echo json_encode($res_array);

mysqli_free_result($res);

mysqli_close($con);
```

I wonder if there is any settings that I have to change before running the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `$res_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);` will only fetch one record.

You need to loop over result-set object and get all data from that.So use `while()` loop like below

```
$res_array =[];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
  $res_array[] = $row;
}
```

Reference:-

[mysqli_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, it's all over [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php):

> **mysqli_fetch_assoc** Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows.

Note "the fetched row" part.

You need to do put your gathering in a cycle

```
$rows = [];

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row
}

json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace this line

```
$res_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
```

with

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $res_array[] = $row;
}
```